# Grouping items from an array

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have a TWIG/PHP array that is similar to the following:

```
Item [
    Item Name,
    Item Ref Number,
    Item Quantity,
    Item Amount,
]
```

I can have multiple lines in an Item so for example:

```
Item [
    [ Item 1, 0001ABC, 1, 100, ],
    [ Item 2, 0002ADD, 1, 200, ],
    [ Item 3, 0001ABC, 1, 200, ],
    [ Item 4, 0002BDS, 3, 100, ],
]
```

When the **Ref Number** matches, in this example Item 1 and 3, how can I group and show only these two instances and keep the other Items separate so that the output would show something similar to this:
Layout 1 (only when there are grouped items)

```
.---------------------------------.
Item 1, 0001ABC, 1, 100
Item 3, 0001ABC, 1, 200
.---------------------------------.
```

Layout 2 (Only when there are individual items)

```
.---------------------------------.
Item 2, 0002ADD, 1, 200
.---------------------------------.
Item 4, 0002BDS, 3, 100
.---------------------------------.
```

Comment: Group the data in your controller, doing this in twig would be overkill

Comment: What would you do, the raw data is coded in JSON, would you just provide an iterative grouped flag where there are duplicates?

Comment: Here is an example in [twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325567/ordering-an-array-of-object-with-twig/54326427#54326427) and here is an example in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166265/group-parent-and-child-categories-together-with-posts-and-display-using-timber-t/66168187#66168187)